# document.evaluate working in google chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, document.evaluate

The following code is working perfectly in google chrome but in firefox it's returning an empty array.

```
var spans = document.evaluate( ".//span[contains(@class, '_GAmD') and not(contains(@class, '_GAe'))]/text()", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE , null);
```

Comment: Just for fun, try removing the `.` at the beginning of your XPath expression.

Comment: The result is same without the .(dot).